# Estimating Simpson's Index with vegan package for single days in R

Tags: r, indexing

I have a huge data set of nature observations like this:

fulldata:

```
 Date           Number     Species      Weekday

 2019-04-30      15           A           Tue
 2019-04-30       7           A           Tue
 2019-04-30      40           C           Tue
 2019-05-01       3           C           Wed
 2019-05-01      25           B           Wed
 2019-05-02       6           A           Thu
 2019-05-03      38           D           Fri
 2019-05-03       1           E           Fri
```

Here is a dput of a sample of 15 observations from the data set:

```
structure(list(
Date = structure(c(18031, 18034, 18018, 18044, 18026, 18037, 18016, 18021, 18042, 18045, 18038, 18036, 18046, 18040, 18042), class = "Date"), 
Number = c(1L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 4L,5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L,1L),
Species = c("Andrena fulva", "Clytus arietis", "Allium ursinum", "Erinaceus europaeus", "Vulpes vulpes", "Alauda arvensis", "Bombus indet.", "Noctua janthe", "Falco tinnunculus", "Pica pica", "Mimas tiliae", "Sylvia borin", "Silene dioica", "Merops apiaster", "Eurygaster austriaca"),
Weekday = c("Wed", "Sat", "Thu", "Tue", "Fri", "Tue", "Tue", "Sun", "Sun", "Wed", "Wed", "Mon", "Thu", "Fri", "Sun")),
row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

In fulldata there are a total of over 12.000 observations. The Date is in as.Date format, Number is numeric, Species and Weekday are character variables.

What I need to do is get the Simpson's Index of diversity for every single Date so they can be compared later. The ultimate goal is to see if there a differences in the observed diversity on weekdays vs. on the weekend. As a first step I made separate data frames for every single Date. There are 32 different days, so I now have 32 smaller data frames with the same variables as fulldata. On every single day there are over a 1.000 different species (Species) reported and each observation also includes the number (Number) of individuals detected.

My question now is: can I use the vegan package to estimate the different Simpson's Index values and if yes how? I'm not sure if it will work with the separate variables Number and Species or if the number of individuals observed has to be represented by the rows.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: can you please share a dput of a part of your data?

Comment: I edited the original post and added a dput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work as long as the species names are consistently spelled. Assuming your sample data is called `species`:

```
library(vegan)
species.tbl <- xtabs(Number~Date+Species, species)
species.simp <- diversity(species.tbl, "simpson")
species.simp
# 2019-04-30 2019-05-02 2019-05-05 2019-05-10 2019-05-15 2019-05-18 2019-05-20 2019-05-21 2019-05-22 2019-05-24 2019-05-26 2019-05-28 2019-05-29 2019-05-30 
#        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.5        0.0        0.0        0.0
```